# global servlet page view counter, Is this thread-safe and will it produce accurate

Tags: java, tomcat, concurrency

If all my servlets inherit from my own BaseServlet, and this BaseServlet has a single proprety:

```
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static AtomicLong pageViews;
}
```

And then I put:

```
pageViews.getAndIncrement()
```

Somewhere in the DoGet() such that all sub-classes will also call this code (by calling super?), will this be thread-safe and produce accurate results?

The app will be hosted on a single server with tomcat, but if I use multiple servers then I plan on flushing this value to the db every 1K increments (and I will add that value to whatever is in the db, or create a new row with the value of the atomic long).

Will this work?

**Update**

When I flush to the database, I also will need to reset the counter value to 0.  I guess I then need to create a method which is marked as synchronize and then get the value, save to db, then reset to 0?

Comment: Maybe @BalusC can comment as it is trying to put multhreading/concurrency into practice with servlets now (for me) :)

Answer (score 2):

The AtomicLonig would work.  It would be both thread safe and accurate.

Flushing to the database works fine too as long as you only use the modify/get methods (like incrementAndGet).  If it looks like

```
public void doGet(){
   int currentView = pageViews.incrementAndGet(); 
   //only one thread will view currentView as 1000 all others will be + or -.  

   if(currentView % 1000 == 0) update(currentview);
}
```

If you start using the `get()` method then you can have other threads read 1000.

Edit:

My solution would only work if you maintained the count throughout the lifetime of the application.  Resetting the count to 0 on a 1000 hit would result in loss increments.

The issue with your `synchronized` is that you would have to `synchronize` each time you increment and evaluate if its 1000 (and of course the db update).  If that is the case you could just use a plain `long`.  Though I am not sure if you want to halt all user requests to that servlet for every 1000 users while it updates the DB.

Comment: also when I flush, I'll synchronize and reset the counter to 0.

Comment: that throws a wrench to this solution then.  Setting to 0 if equal to 1000 wouldn't be atomic

Comment: You would more then likely have to create a separate thread taking requests to increment the value.

Comment: the problem with maintaining the count is, when I restart tomcat, it will be reset. the db is what will have the official value.

Answer (score 0):

Every servlet instance inheriting from `BaseServlet` will have its own instance of `pageViews`.

To increment it in the subclass, it would have to be at least `protected` instead of `private`.

<strike>The counter will ***not* be shared** between all servlet instances. From your question I get the impression you want to have a global counter for all pageviews.</strike> For that you need to create a singleton instance of the counter. Making the counter `static` might work, but I think it would be better to create a separate class instance for this singleton counter.

**update**

I see that you added the `static` keyword in your edit. Now that you voiced the fact that you want to use the counter to call bussiness logic flushing data to the database I would use a completely separate singleton instance to handle the increments and saving to the database. The servlets would call something like:

```
int myCount = MyDatabaseCache.getInstance().countAndFlush();
```

where the flush method follows the pattern:

```
public synchronized int countAndFlush() {

    if (counter++ >= FLUSH_COUNT) {

        // flush to database
        // (alternatively spawn a thread to do the work

        counter = 0;
     }
     return counter;
 }
```